# Why would XCode 8.2.1 be applying an ARC rule to a non-ARC file?

Tags: objective-c, xcode8

I'm working on a legacy project that has both ARC and non-ARC modules.  I'm getting an ARC related compiler error ("ARC forbids Objecive-C objects in struct") from a file (SectionedTableModel.h) that is not using ARC though.

I have verified the following
The project setting for "Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting" is NO

There are no compiler flags set for SectionedTableModel.m, while some other files do have "-fobjc-arc" set.  I even tried setting "fno-objc-arc" but it made no difference.

I'm thinking this has to be a bug with the most recent version of XCode, but before I file a radar incident, thought I would see if anyone has any other ideas or suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the .h file was being included by a .m file that WAS set for ARC, which was enough to trigger the warning?  Makes some sense but a little counter-intuitive.